# Mysql + SQLAlchemy + Pylons Issue

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pylons

I'm trying to setup my models in Pylons using a MySQL backend and I keep getting the following:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/paster", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('PasteScript==1.7.3', 'console_scripts', 'paster')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PasteScript-1.7.3-py2.6.egg/paste/script/command.py", line 84, in run
    invoke(command, command_name, options, args[1:])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PasteScript-1.7.3-py2.6.egg/paste/script/command.py", line 123, in invoke
    exit_code = runner.run(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PasteScript-1.7.3-py2.6.egg/paste/script/command.py", line 218, in run
    result = self.command()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PasteScript-1.7.3-py2.6.egg/paste/script/serve.py", line 276, in command
    relative_to=base, global_conf=vars)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PasteScript-1.7.3-py2.6.egg/paste/script/serve.py", line 313, in loadapp
    **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PasteDeploy-1.3.3-py2.6.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 204, in loadapp
    return loadobj(APP, uri, name=name, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PasteDeploy-1.3.3-py2.6.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 225, in loadobj
    return context.create()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PasteDeploy-1.3.3-py2.6.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 625, in create
    return self.object_type.invoke(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PasteDeploy-1.3.3-py2.6.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 110, in invoke
    return fix_call(context.object, context.global_conf, **context.local_conf)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PasteDeploy-1.3.3-py2.6.egg/paste/deploy/util/fixtypeerror.py", line 57, in fix_call
    val = callable(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/kyle/kyleterry/kyleterry/config/middleware.py", line 38, in make_app
    load_environment(global_conf, app_conf)
  File "/home/kyle/kyleterry/kyleterry/config/environment.py", line 41, in load_environment
    engine = engine_from_config(config, 'sqlalchemy.')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.5.2-py2.6.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/__init__.py", line 241, in engine_from_config
    return create_engine(url, **opts)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.5.2-py2.6.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/__init__.py", line 223, in create_engine
    return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.5.2-py2.6.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 62, in create
    dbapi = dialect_cls.dbapi(**dbapi_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.5.2-py2.6.egg/sqlalchemy/databases/mysql.py", line 1456, in dbapi
    import MySQLdb as mysql
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3c1-py2.6-linux-i686.egg/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3c1-py2.6-linux-i686.egg/_mysql.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3c1-py2.6-linux-i686.egg/_mysql.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: libmysqlclient_r.so.15: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I've tried searching for the answer online but nothing seems to work.

EDIT: This has been solved. The best approach can be found here: http://docs.turbogears.org/1.0/DatabaseMySQL

Comment: An answer explaining how you got from that page of TurboGears docs to the solution to your problem would be a good idea, and helpful to others.